# The same code in one project create a UIView with rounded corners and in another project with wired looking corners

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

This code:

```
item.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
item.layer.clipToBounds = YES;
```

in one project creates this
[image]

and in the other:
[image]

Comment: I would guess they target different releases.

Comment: @HotLicks you mean development target?

Comment: have you added the `QuartzCore` framework?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write `item.layer.masksToBounds=YES`

Also depending on your screen size, you should check which corner radius will suite, sometimes 5 is not enough

Comment: item.layer.masksToBounds=YES creates the exact same behavior and increasing the corner size doesn't help. my screen is a standard iPhone device (4,5,6)